# Are all Twitter User IDs unique? What happens when a user deletes her account, does her User ID become open for use again?

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

Idk if this question is so simple but I'm new about twitter and I'm trying to understand how it works.

I am trying to learn how Twitter User IDs work. Are they similar with fingerprints? What happens to the ID of a user when she deletes her account, does her User ID become open for use again?

**Does Twitter assign her user ID to a new user?**

Comment: Question has nothing to do with most of those tags. and not sure why you'd want to know if Twitter recycle the user IDs. From experience it's so much easier not to.

Comment: I'm trying to make a bot and I'll take Twitter User IDs as objects. That's why I should know are they recycling. If they are recycling, I need to find another way to make accounts Unique. As I researched, Twitter uses Snowflake IDs for Tweets but I need to know whether user IDs are unique or not. I thought tags are okay, a person who uses twitter api can know the answer I guess.

Answer (score 0):

A Twitter user ID (numeric) is indeed unique.

A Twitter user "handle" / username is unique while it is being used. If a user changes their username, or deletes their account, that username can be used by another user. It will not be the same user account, because the user account is associated to the user ID (numeric), not to the name.

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks for answer. Additionally, do you know whether Twitter user IDs can be recycled or not. If a deleted account's ID is recycled and assigned to a new user, do you know any unique value that can identify a user.

Comment: A user ID (numeric 64 bit) is always unique. Twitter never recycles that value. That is the answer.